# Elastic how to define a mapping given another field value

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is what I have as data :

```
 {
          "firstname" : "blablabla",
              ...
          "otherDatas" : [
            {
              "reference" : "40xxx1372",
              "universe" : "marketing",
              "dataType" : "id"
            },
            {
              "reference" : "roleA",
              "universe" : "finance",
              "dataType" : "role"
            }
          ],
        }
```

What I would need to do is create a mapping for otherDatas special case like having otherDatas.role.reference : keyword only if my otherDatas has the datatype "role"

So I could search for all user having a given role in the organisation

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also equally important to understand what type `values` go into the `key` before you design your mapping. Please look into the differences between `text` , and `keyword` types. I assume all those fields are `keyword`, meaning one word and not needed any analysis on those values.

Coming to your mapping, I believe `nested` object probably confused you. Here is how you go about it (and let me know if you have any specific questions)

```
PUT so_test14
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc":{
      "properties":{
        "firstname": {"type":"keyword"},

        "otherDatas": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "reference": {"type": "keyword"},
            "universe": {"type": "keyword"},
            "dataType": {"type": "keyword"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @JBone, thanks for your answer. I think I understand the difference between keyword and text and in my case I indeed need both keywords and text because you have to be able to search by reference (approximatively ) and in specific case like when the reference is about a specific datatype   I need term search (exact ones)

Comment: Ok, sorry I misread the nested object documentation, I can indeed use it to answer my needs. thanks a lot